# What happens to SIVB put option holders?

Tags: options, put-options, bankruptcy

As title implies - I own put options (Strike Price $125, exp. March 17 2023).  I am wondering what happens to other owners of put options.

As we all know now, SIVB is in receivership.  I do not own shares of SIVB, only put options. Due to trading being halted, I cannot acquire shares, so I'm curious as to what happens.  Do put options holders get some form of compensation?  I am aware that put options holders are entitled to the strike price x100 per contact, but I'm unsure of how that works, and when.

I use WeBull as my options trading platform, if that info is of any use.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens to my put options on RSX expiring March 18 2022, if RSX remains halted then?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/149699/what-happens-to-my-put-options-on-rsx-expiring-march-18-2022-if-rsx-remains-hal)

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD not sure it does. In that case people are short shares that exist that they can't possibly buy because of sanctions and having to pay 80% interest forever. In this case the shares will probably no longer exist on by the expiry date as the company will have been dissolved. If they do exist they'll be worth $0.

Comment: Investing carries risk of loss.  You (and many others) lost.

Comment: Ron - you sure that’s so? What would happen to a short seller? it would seem that there would be no ability to buy the shares back, which is what the short seller needs to do to close out their position. Why would this be any different?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same position in my IRA account at TD. They told me that they cannot settle it (as prescribed by the OCC, meaning through a broker to broker transaction).

Comment: An answer needs to say what happens since you can't settle it.